# Linking to Sections: do it or do something different?

Tags: templating, sections

I'm pretty new to Craft, so I'd like to know if there's a best practice when linking to a section, assuming the section has an `index.html` template for its "homepage."

I'm currently using the following to loop through all Sections and then give me their URL, but in sort of a hacky way. This is one of a couple ways I've found to do this, but my Homepage singlepage entry outputs as `http://example.com/__home__` which is super weird.

```
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}  

{% for section in sections %}
    <li class="nav__link" id="nav__link--{{ section.handle }}">
        <a href="{{ siteUrl }}{{ section.template|split('/')[0] }}">{{ section }}</a>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

```

If the best practice is to do something completely different, then feel free to set me straight! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've found what is probably a better solution;

I create a Single section for each Channel/Structure and use that as a directory for that channel/structure. I then loop through all sections and see if they're of the single type, then get the first (and only) entry of that section.

```
{# Get all Section #}
{% set sections = craft.sections.getAllSections() %}

{# Loop through all single sections #}
{% for singleSection in sections if singleSection.type == 'single' %}

    {# Get the first (and only) entry of that section #}
    {% set singleEntry = craft.entries.sectionId(singleSection.id).first %}

    {# Output #}
     <li class="nav__link">
        <a href="{{ singleEntry.url }}" class="section-link">{{ singleSection }}</a>
    </li>

{% endfor %}
```

Let me know if you guys have a better way of doing this!

Comment: This will work fine until you need a `single` that you otherwise do not want to include in the nav. You might be better served by creating a dedicated 'navigation' section/structure , with an entry field that points to the correct page. That way you can control the order and what is and is not included.

Comment: I've gotten around this problem with a lightswitch field to include that particular entry in the nav or not. As always ymmv.